# How to Install Red5 Server on mac?

Tags: ios, iphone, broadcast, red5

How to install Red5 server i google but no use i use this link to download but I don't know how install 
https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/releases 
Can any body give the link for  dmg file please help me

Comment: We don't create the dmg any more because I dont have a mac. The dmg build stuff can be found here https://github.com/Red5/installer/tree/master/macosx